# Merging 2 XML from URL using XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt

i'm working with an API that gives me two URLs to pull the content from.

The first one gives me a list of products but with limited information about each.

The second url, by using ?productId=1 i can pull the rest of the data about a specific product.

What i'm trying to do is to merge these two things into one, so i could easily import to a wordpress or somewhere else later on.

I've tried doing it with DOM+PHP and i couldn't get it to work, perhaps the xsl would be the better solution?

**File1.svc**

```
<products>
  <product>
    <product_id> 1 </product_id>
    <product_name> Product 1 </product_name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <product_id> 2 </product_id>
    <product_name> Product 2 </product_name>
  </product>
</products>
```

**File2.svc?productId=1**

```
<results>
  <product product_id="1">
    <price_from> 100 </price_from>
    <price_to> 300 </price_to>
  </product>
</results>
```

**Result i want to export:**

```
<products>
  <product>
    <product_id> 1 </product_id>
    <product_name> Product 1 </product_name>
    <price_from> 100 </price_from>
    <price_to> 300 </price_to>
  </product>
  <product>
    <product_id> 2 </product_id>
    <product_name> Product 2 </product_name>
    <price_from> 400 </price_from>
    <price_to> 500 </price_to>
  </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work well:

```
#File1.svc
$xml_A = <<<XML
<products>
    <product>
        <product_id> 1 </product_id>
        <product_name> Product 1 </product_name>
    </product>  
</products>
XML;

#File2.svc?productId=1
$xml_B = <<<XML
<results>
    <product product_id="1">
        <price_from> 100 </price_from>
        <price_to> 300 </price_to>
    </product>
</results>
XML;

$a = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_A); //or new SimpleXMLElement($URL, null, true);
$b = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_B); //or new SimpleXMLElement($URL, null, true);

$priceFromElement = $b->product[0]->price_from;
$priceToElement   = $b->product[0]->price_to;

$a->product[0]->addChild($priceFromElement->getName(), $priceFromElement);
$a->product[0]->addChild($priceToElement->getName(), $priceToElement);

echo $a->asXML(); //merged
```

Comment: the only issue i'm findind at the moment, is that for the XML B to be loaded, i need to give the url a productId. 

Something like

    products.svc/product?&productId=1

This productId will come from the XML A

does that make sense?

Comment: @user3011135 No problem! You can provide bool TRUE to data_is_url param (third argument). See, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could parse them, build them on an array, then create another one. Consider this example:

```
// if you want rough and gun processing
$data = array();
// sample values
@$raw_xml1 = simplexml_load_string('<products> <product> <product_id> 1 </product_id> <product_name> Product 1 </product_name> </product> <product> <product_id> 2 </product_id> <product_name> Product 2 </product_name> </product></products>');
@$raw_xml2 = simplexml_load_string('<results> <product product_id="1"> <price_from> 100 </price_from> <price_to> 300 </price_to> </product> <product product_id="2"> <price_from>400</price_from> <price_to>500</price_to> </product></results>');

// the extraction
foreach($raw_xml1->product as $key => $value) {
    $product_id = trim((string) $value->product_id);
    $data[$product_id] = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'product_name' => trim((string) $value->product_name),
    );
}

foreach($raw_xml2->product as $key => $value) {
    $product_id = trim((string) $value->attributes()['product_id']);
    $data[$product_id]['price_from'] = trim((string) $value->price_from);
    $data[$product_id]['price_to'] = trim((string) $value->price_to);
}

$final_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$final_xml .= '<products>';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $final_xml .= '<product>';
    foreach($value as $index => $element) {
        $final_xml .= "<$index>$element</$index>";
    }
    $final_xml .= '</product>';
}
$final_xml .= '</products>';

// save it
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($final_xml);
$xml->asXML('text.xml');
// saved as xml file, should be saved on the same level as this php
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a XSLT solution which selects the file according to the ID attached to the filename:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="products">
        <copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="product_id"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="product_name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="filepath" select="concat('File2.svc?productId=',normalize-space(product_id))"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document($filepath)/results/product/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It *could* also check if the ID *attribute* is correct, but I assumed that checking `?productId=` was enough since it filters the results by the ID as you said.